# How do I initialize a character variable in fortran 77?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

Consider the variable

```
    character*100 xx
```

I want to initialize it to some value, possibly some printable character or blanks. I tried

```
    data xx /100*char(120)/
```

But that did not work.
Minimum working example:

```
cat car_array.F 
    character*10 xx
    data xx /10*char(120)/
    write(*,*)xx
    end


   ifort car_array.F 
   car_array.F(2): error #6169: This construct is not valid in this context.   [CHAR]
          data xx /10*char(120)/
  --------------------^
  compilation aborted for car_array.F (code 1)
```

Comment: What does it mean *that did not work*? It does not say anything useful. Error messages? Wrong results? Which ones? Please show some compilable example([mcve]).

Comment: added more details

Comment: Now I see, `char()`  is not allowed in the DATA statement.

Comment: you also can not repeat characters that way, `data xx /10*'x'/` will not work either. ( I wouldn't be surprised if some compiler took that though )

Comment: Since you are using ifort, you don't have to restrict yourself to F77. Don't assume that just because you're using fixed-form source that it is F77!

Answer (score 2):

making a bold assumption that you don't really need to be f77 standard compliant,
you should try:

```
  character*10 :: xx=repeat(char(120),10)
```

in f77 you would have needed to make this a runtime assignment,

```
  character*10 xx
  integer i
  do i=1,10
  xx(i:i)=char(120)
  end do
```

the only way  i see to use a repeat count `data` statement to initialize a string in f77 is via equivalence with a length 1 character array, and here you can not use the `char` function

```
  equivalence(x,y)
  character*10 x
  character*1 y(10)
  data y/10*'a'/
  write(*,*)x
```

> aaaaaaaaaa

Comment: funny. There seems to be no simple way of doing this. I will wait a day or two before accepting this answer..

Comment: f77 made a lot of things cumbersome. That's why *nobody* should be using it.

Comment: There's no need to stick to F77 - use of repeat is exactly the way it should be done in any compiler that supports F2003, which ifort does.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to agentp's post.
You can use the CHAR() function indirectly if you use it in a compile-time PARAMETER statement.
Old-timey, but this works on openVMS Fortran.

```
 PARAMETER CHAR_120 = CHAR(120)

 CHARACTER*1     X(10)   /10*CHAR_120/
 CHARACTER*10    XX
 EQUIVALENCE (X, XX)

 TYPE *,XX
```

Comment: I managed to compile this in gfortran, but you have to declare `CHAR_120` as `CHARACTER` and you have to use correct Fortran syntax for parameters: `PARAMETER (CHAR_120 = CHAR(120))`. The parentheses are NOT optional. Also, the superugly `TYPE` must be changed to `PRINT`.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that this style of variable initialization `CHARACTER*1     X(10)   /10*CHAR_120/` is also not standard. But gfortran, and presumably other compilers too, compiles it.

Comment: What I posted was tested. The DEC (openVMS) F77 compiler assumes a datatype on the PARAMETER statement (character, integer or floating)  based on what you equate the parameter to.  It also supports the separate declaration and PARAMETER using parenthesis as you show in your comment. I did not know that was more standard.  TYPE * is just a 30 year habit.

Comment: I am just saying that not all that passes a test in one compiler is conforming to standard Fortran 77. Many compilers accept many non-standard stuff.

Comment: This: `PARAMETER CHAR_120 = CHAR(120)` can mean a simple assignment to variable `PARAMETERCHAR_120` in standard Fortran when we allow more than 6 characters. I assume that is the reason for the necessity of the parentheses.

Comment: Understand and agree in general. The "F77" openVMS compiler has a number of extensions, some before the F77 standard. The various vendors lobbied for what became the standard, mostly after they had made their own extensions. I posted an answer using the compiler I have access to in order to post a tested answer. And, truth be told, do not know which features are "standard" and which are not.  Cheers!